# FLASK: Поиск и вывод результата из БД

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

Не получается вывести результат поиска на страницу. При нажатие на кнопку переходит на все тот же index.html без всякого результата, хотя по задумке планируется выводить результат на result.html

Имеется:

### routes.py

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        result = Coop.query.filter_by(name=form.product.data).first()
        flash(result)
        return redirect(url_for('result.html', products=result))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)


@app.route('/result')
def result(products):
    render_template('result.html', products=products)
```

### forms.py

```
class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    product = StringField('Product', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

### index.html

```
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="GET">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <p>
        {{ form.product.label }}
        {{ form.product(size=32) }}
        {{ form.submit() }}
    </p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

### result.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<table>
       <tr>
        <td>
            {{ products.id }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ products.date }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ products.name }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

### models.py

```
class Coop(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<id = {}, date = {}, name = {}>'.format(self.id, 
        self.date, self.name)
```

Comment: Читайте ошибки у формы. Непонятно, почему вы их не вывели на index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так не получится:

Во-первый, если выборка из базы данных будет пустой, то получится, что redirect вы вызовите с пустым products - ошибка (products - обязательный параметр для функции result).

Во-вторых, если выборка из БД будет не пустой, то функции flash и redirect выдадут ошибку - они попытаются сериализовать объект result в json!

Здесь два варианта:

1. Вызвать непосредственно render_template('result.html', products=result) вместо redirect.
2. Если redirect очень необходим, то передать в качестве параметра не объект result, а одно поле (result.id) и в функции result заново произвести выборку и вывести в браузер.

### routes.py

```
 @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 @app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def index():
     form = SearchForm(request.form)
     if form.validate_on_submit():
         result = Coop.query.filter_by(name=form.product.data).first()
         if result:
             flash(result.name)
             return render_template('result.html', products=result)

     return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

### index.html

```
 {% block content %}
 <form action="" method="POST">
     {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
     <p>
         {{ form.product.label }}
         {{ form.product(size=32) }}
         {{ form.submit() }}
     </p>
 </form>
 {% endblock %}
```